# tidyverse grouping combining small groups into "other"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's say I want summarize a certain data frame column:

```
> starwars %>% count(eye_color)
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   eye_color         n
   <chr>         <int>
 1 black            10
 2 blue             19
 3 blue-gray         1
 4 brown            21
 5 dark              1
 6 gold              1
 7 green, yellow     1
 8 hazel             3
 9 orange            8
10 pink              1
11 red               5
12 red, blue         1
13 unknown           3
14 white             1
15 yellow           11
```

There are a lot of small categories, such as "blue-gray" or "pink". I would like to merge them all into "other". There is a multi-step process to do this:

```
starwars %>%
add_count(eye_color) %>%
mutate(eye_color = if_else(n < 5, "other", eye_color)) %>%
count(eye_color)
```

There is also a way to do it with a single command. I saw this trick before somewhere, but now cannot find it.

Comment: Are you thinking of `forcats::fct_lump`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing up @Jordan's suggestion:

Updated: with Camille's fix:

```
starwars %>%  mutate(eye_color_grp = as.factor(eye_color) %>%
                       forcats::fct_lump_min(min = 5, other_level = "Other")) %>%
  count(eye_color_grp, sort = TRUE)
```

Link:https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html

Comment: Take a look at the docs for this function: `fct_lump` with `n = 5` keeps the 5 most commonly occurring levels, whereas `fct_lump_min` with `min = 5` keeps levels which appear at least 5 times. The latter matches the OP's `if_else` statement.

Comment: You can actually skip `as.factor()`.